# Create CSS using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So In javascript you can do things like

```
document.querySelector('html').style.filter = 'invert(100%)'
```

Which Inverts colors on the entire webpage
but is there anyway to use

```
document.querySelector('html').style.pointer = 'something'
```

or a way to
add a css rule or something to the document?

example
you have an element like this

hello

then js gives an class
hello
then js adds a css rule?

.why {}

Comment: Also, look at [@Erasmo Hernandez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384745/14950361) for giving class to element. My answer is just to add CSS to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write to the document using `document.write`

```js
document.write(`
<style>
  #text {
    color: red;
  }
</style>`)
```

```html
<h1 id='text'>Hello</h1>
```

Or, you can also create an element and append it to the document

```js
let style = document.createElement('style')
style.innerHTML = `
.text {
  color: red;
}
`

document.body.appendChild(style)
```

```html
<h1 class='text'>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css class to specific element with (and then create the styles from the css file):

```
[NameOfTheElement].classList.add("mystyle")
```

This will work for the document:

```
document.querySelector('html').classList.add('new-class');
```

This will work for the body:

```
document.querySelector('body').classList.add('new-body-class')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways.

1. If you already have styles defined for a certain class within your stylesheet, you can do what Erasmo said above:

```
element.classList.add('className');
```

2. You can also use:

```
element.style.color = 'white';
```

3. Or add a style attribute to the element:

```
element.setAttribute('style', 'color: white; background-color: green;');
```